# Features of PHP SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am wondering the features that are fully supported within PHP Soap, I have tried researching this, but there is very little documentation to support PHP Soap.

Also how is Soap used during the exchange of data through client machine to web service then server.

I know this is fairly vague, but as I am constantly being asked this myself I thought it was better to find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some build in SOAP classes for both client and server. Docs is on [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

But you have to be sure that your PHP build is compilled with SOAP support.

Answer (score 0):

"The features that are fully supported within PHP" are pretty much non-existent.

Built in SOAP client is ok only for basic services. It doesn't support any WS extensions, so you have to add support manually, e.g. including headers for WS-Security.

Also, there are some problems with namespace handling and creating requests.

If you'll be using it and are having trouble with missing parameters or badly formatted requests, you'll probably want to modify requests - this can be done by extending SoapClient class and overriding doRequest function.